# how to integrate HTML5 in visual studio 2008

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008

Can anyone give the steps for integrating the html5 language in visual studio 2008?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The web standards update for Visual Studio 2010 is what gives you the syntax highlighting for both HTML5 and CSS3.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it is available for vs2008, sorry.  There may be a user supported extension out there,  but not one from Microsoft.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/06/15/web-standards-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx